# Multipass VM size on disk too large

Tags: virtualization, multipass

I have a multipass VM for running Kubernetes. Some Kubernetes workloads took up a lot of space in the VM. I have cleared that space within the VM now but on the host machine the space occupied on the VM has not gone down. In fact it has gone up from 37.2 GB to 46.2 GB!

How do I reclaim space and make it usable on the host machine without deleting the VM?

Size of VM as seen from host:
[image]

Output of `df -h` inside the VM:
[image]

Comment: The problem is that the host can not know the difference between a file containing zeros and real deleteded content. Therefore it only keeps growing - but gladly there are tools to re-sparsify this - have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/432119/is-there-any-way-to-shrink-qcow2-image-without-converting-it-raw

Comment: I had left it alone for a few days, and now it has shrunk in size. There have been a few host reboots during that time. I guess, it take a reboot for the auto cleanup.